# WebChromeClient onShowFileChooser()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, onactivityresult, filechooser

I'm trying the input file tag in html to get it to in my WebView. I'm creating a chooser intent so the user can select whether he wants to take a new picter or pick an existing one from the gallery. My problem is that in onActivityResult() the result code is -1 instead of 0 and no matter what is picked from the chooser, the intent action is always the same.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(
            WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
            WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onShowFileChooser()");

        this.mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

        final Intent chooserIntent = createChooserIntent();
        this.mainActivity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        return true;
    }

    private Intent createChooserIntent() {
        final Intent imageCaptureIntent = this.createImageCaptureIntent();
        final Intent imagePickerIntent = this.createImagePickerIntent();

        final Intent imageChooserMenuIntent = Intent.createChooser(imagePickerIntent, "Image Chooser");
        imageChooserMenuIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[] {imageCaptureIntent});

        return imageChooserMenuIntent;
    }

    private Intent createImagePickerIntent() {
        final Intent imagePickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        imagePickerIntent.setType("image/*");

        return imagePickerIntent;
    }

    private Intent createImageCaptureIntent() {
        final Intent imageCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "Avatar.jpg");
        this.mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
        imageCaptureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, this.mCapturedImageURI);

        return imageCaptureIntent;
    }
```

And the onActivityResult():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult(): " + requestCode + " " + resultCode);

    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (data.getAction() == MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "FROM CAMERA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "FROM PICKER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //TO DO: get the picture and pass it to onReceiveValue();

        this.webChromeClient.getmFilePathCallback().onReceiveValue(null);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me?